# How do I reinstall windows 10 apps and store, powershell commands not working

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I have tried all powershell commands that I could find on the internet that say will reinstall my windows 10 default apps with no luck, some commands get the shell working but lead to nothing but errors.
Here are some of the ones I tried:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers| Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}

Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

And I even tried reinstalling windows store as instructed on this [website](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-restore-windows-store-in-windows-10-after-removing-it-with-powershell/)  and the powershell command tells it cannot find the path because it does not exist..

[image]
[image]

I don't remember ever removing them, they just randomly disappeared one day, and here's what I was left with:
[image]

Any suggestions? It's been weeks I've been trying to fix this with no progress and I don't want to reset my pc.

Comment: The commands you are trying to use do not work on `Windows 10 Version 1511` and there are no such equivalent commands that do work.  You will have to Reset your installation to achieve what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Additionally, you had curly double quotes in your first PS command line of `"$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}` which I just edited to make normal double quotes in your answer. Likely an HTML\web browser site copy and paste issue.